# Using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule to pass the referrer into the querystring

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to capture the refuring url or the complete html link
i.e."(http.bbserver.edu/john_doe/quiz.doc)"
and send it to a php script.

I've got it to slightly work with the following

```
REWRITERULE ([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ login.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER}&path=$0&folder=$1&file=$2 [NC,L]
```

But the php file prints out this

```
Referer:
path: John_Doe/quiz.doc
folder: John_Doe/quiz.doc
file: quiz.doc
```

if I try this, attempting to get everything and send it to the php script.

```
REWRITERULE ^(.+)$ login.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER}&path=$0&folder=$1&file=$2 [NC,L]
```

But the php file prints out this.

```
Referer:
path: login.php
folder: login.php
file:
```

I would like to capture "HTTP_REFERER" and parse the subfolders and file through php.
But I'm not getting the information I need.

Comment: Since I stumbles here, too, just a quick note when using this together with [Helicon ISAPI Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteCond.htm): Instead of `%{HTTP_REFERER}` it is there `%{HTTP:Referer}`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that HTTP_REFERER is being set?  Often it won't be if you're behind an HTTP proxy.  Try printing the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, which should also contain the value of the HTTP referrer if that is being set.

If you are behind a proxy and you need the referrer, you can use [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/), and get the referrer from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.

Comment: I called our I.T. Dept and we are not behind a HTTP proxy.  I print the value in the PHP script and it is empty.  Do I need to enable anything?

Comment: Not in Apache, AFAICT.  But it does depend on the client:  browsers can choose not to send a Referer: header, in order to improve the user's privacy.  If you've been testing with just one browser, then either check the privacy settings in that browser, or try a different browser and/or a different client host.

Comment: Also I created a virtual host and saved the rewrite rules in our .conf file.  Could a Virtual host also cause problems.  Plus is there any other method to get the referer without mod_rewrite?

Comment: The virtual host doesn't matter.  In PHP, you can get all of the important server variables in [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Try using `curl -v` to fetch your page, so you can see the headers that are being sent.  That will show you whether `Referer:` is being sent, and what the result is.

Comment: Well we did get it to work slightly.  But it is returning the client ip address, not the server where the link is stored.  I may be expecting too much from any web server.  I simply want to get the server that contains the link that the user clicked to direct them to our server.  To me it seems an imposible task.  But the Dean of our Dept says it can be done.

Comment: The client is responsible for sending a Referer header.  The server can only report what the client sends, and the client can send the right thing, or the wrong thing, or nothing, at its option.